# Knockoutjs - Can I use data-bind attr together with i18n?

Tags: knockout.js, magento2

I'm modifying a template in magento2, which have this chunk of code:

```
<a href="#"
   class="item-action action-gift"
   data-bind="
   attr: {title: 'Gift Options'}
   ">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Gift options'"></span>
</a>
```

I want to be able to translate the title attribute like so

```
<a href="#"
   class="item-action action-gift"
   data-bind="
   attr: {title: i18n:'Gift Options'}
   ">
    <span data-bind="i18n: 'Gift options'"></span>
</a>
```

But that obviously gives error. Is it possible to have i18n in the attr binding? How to do it properly if it is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a custom binding handler that calls a default binding by using `ko.applyBindingsToNode`.

To inject your `i18n` translation step, you create a `ko.pureComputed` representation of your settings object inside the `init` method and call the original `attr` binding with it.

Say we have a function named `i18n` that takes a string and returns another string. We'll go from:

```
attr: { title: "my string" }
```

To

```
attr: { title: i18n("my string") }
```

Here's how we create the computed object that is passed to `attr`:

```
ko.bindingHandlers.i18nAttr = {
  init: function(el, va) {
    var translated = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      // Support observable options objects: unwrap
      var options = ko.unwrap(va());

      return Object
        .keys(options)
        .reduce(function(tOptions, k) {
          // Support observable properties: unwrap
          tOptions[k] = i18n(ko.unwrap(options[k]));
          return tOptions;
        }, {});
    });

    return ko.applyBindingsToNode(el, { attr: translated });
  }
};
```

In a working example: (I created a `computed` i18n function to support toggling on and off translations/switching languages)

```js
ko.bindingHandlers.i18nAttr = {
  init: function(el, va) {
    var translated = ko.pureComputed(function() {
      var options = ko.unwrap(va());
      var translate = i18n();

      return Object
        .keys(options)
        .reduce(function(tOptions, k) {
          tOptions[k] = translate(ko.unwrap(options[k]));
          return tOptions;
        }, {});
    });

    return ko.applyBindingsToNode(el, { attr: translated });
  }
};

var translate = ko.observable(true);
var i18n = translater(translate);

var vm = {
  title: "Elevator",
  placeholder: "Cookie",
  translate: translate
};

ko.applyBindings(vm);


// Mock i18n method
function translater(doTranslate) {
  return ko.pureComputed(function() {
    return doTranslate() 
      ? function(str) { return str; }
      : function(str) {
          return ({
            "Elevator": "Lift",
            "Cookie": "Biscuit"
          })[str];
        };
  });
};
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<input data-bind="i18nAttr: { placeholder: placeholder }"/>
<a data-bind="i18nAttr: { title: title }">hover for title</a>

<label><input type="checkbox" data-bind="checked: translate">Translate</label>
```

Comment: Thanks! this is more complicated than I had expected

Answer (score 2):

- If you're referring to **UI component template** (*.html files) - you could use the $t("ENTER_YOUR_STRING_HERE") function to daisy-chain KnockoutJS's text-binding and achieve internationalization/translation:

[image: Strings added in UI component templates]

- If you're referring to **Magento template** (*.phtml files) - you could use the 
  __("ENTER_YOUR_STRING_HERE") method to achieve internationalization/translation:

[image: Strings added in .phtml templates]

*Source:* https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/frontend-dev-guide/translations/translate_theory.html

Answer (score 1):

This much shorter code could work for you:

```
<a href="#"
           class="item-action action-gift"
           data-bind="
           attr: {title: '${i18n("Gift Options")}'}
           ">
           <span data-bind="i18n: 'Gift options'"></span>
</a>
```